# Find the points on the curve where the tangent is horizontal or vertical.$x = t^3 − 3t, \ y = t^2 − 4$

Tags: calculus

Find the points on the curve where the tangent is horizontal or vertical.

$x = t^3 − 3t, \   y = t^2 − 4$

(Enter your answers as a comma-separated list of ordered pairs.)

horizontal tangent      (x, y) =

vertical tangent    (x, y) =

$dx/dt = 3t2 - 3 
dy/dt = 2t 
dx/dy = 1.5*t - 1.5/t = 0 
t - 1/t = 0 => t2 - 1 = 0 (t ≠ 0) 
=> (t + 1)(t - 1) = 0, t = 1, -1 
t = 1 => x = -2, y = -7 
t = -1 => x = 2, y = -7$

So (-2,-7) and (2,-7).

My answer is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text d x}{\text d t}=3t^2-3=0 \rightarrow t=\pm1$$
Vertical tangent points = $(2,-3)$, $(-2,-3)$
$$\frac{\text d y}{\text d t}=2t=0 \rightarrow t=0$$
Horizontal tangent point = $(0,-4)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{2t}{3t^2-3}$$
for tangent to be horizontal slope is $0$ that is $t=0$
$x=0$,$y=-4$
for vertical tangent slope is infinity
that is $t=+1$ or $t=-1$
substituting $t$ you can get values of $x$ and $y$